# PyQt5 run same thread dynamically

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread

I am useing python 3.7 and pyqt5

What I want to do is run same QObject with different thread many times.

here is my main

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import threading
import sys
from Worker_Starting import Worker_Starting


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI()
        self.initSignal()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton("Stop", self)
        self.pushButton.move(0,0)
        self.pushButton_2.move(120,0)


    def initSignal(self) :
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Start)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Stop)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def Start(self) :
        for i in range(3) :  
            print('main', threading.get_ident())
            input = ["userID", "userNAME"]

            self.my_thread = QThread()
            self.my_worker = Worker_Starting(passing_list=input)
            self.my_worker.moveToThread(self.my_thread)
            self.my_thread.started.connect(self.my_worker.my_fn)
            self.my_thread.start()
            time.sleep(3)


    @pyqtSlot()
    def Stop(self) :
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

and my Qobject

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import time
import threading

class Worker_Starting(QObject):
    def __init__(self, passing_list, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.userid = passing_list[0]
        self.username = passing_list[1]

    def my_fn(self):
        print(self.username, threading.get_ident())
        for i in range(10) :
            Now = time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
            print(str(i) + " : " + self.username + "  running" + " : " + Now)
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

I put `for i in range(3):` under `def start(self):`

because in my actual main script other thread emit input to `def start(self):` several times.

if I emit only one time, `def start(self):` works fine.
but when I emit several times, it chrashs.
since I have to emit several times and I need `my_thread` to work simultaneously and continuously

is there anyway to set same Qobject to different thread?

and how to know or set thread id.

and how to stop thread by thread id.

*I have tried QRunnable, I now it works multi thread. but I have to emit signal back continouously to my main. as far as I know QRunnable are not suitable for custom signal.

Comment: Note that the declaration of `Worker_Starting` inherits from QObject, but you are calling `QtCore.QThread.__init__` instead. Also, it's not necessary to create a new thread and move a QObject to it, as you can normally just subclass QThread instead. Also, you should not use blocking functions like `time.sleep` in the main thread (as you did in `Start()`).

Comment: @musicamante so, If I use QThread instead of QObject, would that solve my problem? 
time.sleep and for i in range(3) was just noticing that I have several eimt signal continuosly to start().

Comment: 1. no, because (as explained in my answer) the issue is that you cannot move a QObject on a different thread while it's still processing on another; my objection was just about the fact that you don't (normally) need to create a QObject subclass and use `moveToThread`, as subclassing from QThread is usually enough (as long as each "working" function is called sequentially, aka no concurrent calls). 2. it doesn't matter: **no** blocking function should ever happen within the main GUI thread, as they should *always* return as soon as possible; using `time.sleep` does *not*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're constantly creating new threads by overwriting the existing one, which results in the previous being garbage collected before it's completed, hence the crash.

If you want to execute the same "worker" function *concurrently*, you cannot use a single object for more threads, as you should use moveToThread each time and this is not possible.

The solution is to use QRunnable instead, implement the function within its `run()` method, and call QThreadPool to run it.

```
class Worker_Starting(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, passing_list):
        QRunnable.__init__(self)
        self.setAutoDelete(False)
        self.userid = passing_list[0]
        self.username = passing_list[1]

    def run(self):
        print(self.username, threading.get_ident())
        for i in range(10) :
            Now = time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
            print(str(i) + " : " + self.username + "  running" + " : " + Now)
            time.sleep(0.5)


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI()
        self.initSignal()
        self.worker = None

    # ...

    def Start(self) :
        if not self.worker:
            input = ["userID", "userNAME"]
            self.worker = Worker_Starting(passing_list=input)
        for i in range(3):
            print('main', threading.get_ident())
            QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(self.worker)
```

Remember that you should *not* use blocking functions within the main Qt thread (that's why I removed `time.sleep(3)` from `Start()`). If you want to start the function more than once at regular intervals, use a QTimer:

```
        interval = 3000 # interval is in milliseconds
        for i in range(3):
            print('main', threading.get_ident())
            QTimer.singleShot(interval * i, lambda:
                QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(self.worker))
```

Note that the `pyqtSlot()` decorator is usually needed only for special cases and advanced implementation, so you should remove it. Also note that only classes and constants should have capitalized names, while functions, variables and attributes should be lower cased (prefer `start` and `stop` instead of `Start` and `Stop`).

Comment: I am aware of Qrunnable do concurrent thread. but is it possible to make custom signal from QRrunnable? and how do I exit specific thread from QRunnable?

Comment: QRunnable doesn't inherit from QObject: no signal can be created (nor emitted, obviously). What you *could* do is to make a QObject subclass with a custom signal, create an instance of that signal for the QRunnable subclass and emit it when needed. But if you want to exit from a specific `QRunnable.run` call, that's another story and it might be even too complex: a simpler option is to create unique QThread workers, keep track of them and stop them when required. Obviously, in order to achieve that, you need some way to constantly check if the thread should stop (usually with a Queue object).